# T-SQL: Question about NOT IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why would these queries return difference results:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ProjectStatus PS 
 WHERE 0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM Project P 
             WHERE P.ProjectStatusKey = PS.ProjectStatusKey)

SELECT * 
  FROM ProjectStatus PS 
 WHERE PS.ProjectStatusKey NOT IN (SELECT P.ProjectStatusKey 
                                     FROM Project P)
```

Comment: Do either of the ProjectStatusKey columns accept NULLs? At first glance, I can't see a reason why they would return different results unless the two columns accept NULL values, and they are being handled differently under the two scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugh. Turns out it is the NULL in the list of options that breaks the whole damn thing. You have to either turn off ANSI NULLs or change the query to this...

```
SELECT * FROM ProjectStatus PS WHERE 
    PS.ProjectStatusKey NOT IN (SELECT P.ProjectStatusKey FROM Project P WHERE P.ProjectStatusKey IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: I was just going to suggest you something like that.  ^_^

Comment: Those darn NULLs cause more trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If any of your Project.ProjectStatusKey values are NULL, then the `NOT IN` clause would evaluate to NULL as well instead of TRUE/FALSE.